# Reactstrap: how to set uncontrolled collapse as open by default

Tags: html, css, reactjs, bootstrap-5, reactstrap

Is there any option to display uncontrolled collapse as opened?

Here is the default code for uncontrolled collapse, it is shown as collapsed tab.

```
<Button color="primary" id="toggler">
  Toggle
</Button>
<UncontrolledCollapse toggler="#toggler">
  <Card>
    <CardBody>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing...
    </CardBody>
  </Card>
</UncontrolledCollapse>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, just add:

```
<UncontrolledCollapse toggler="#toggler" defaultOpen={true}>
...
</UncontrolledCollapse>
```